# How to use sequelize and PostGIS to query by distance?

Tags: sequelize.js, postgis

I have an address model (Sequelize) declared the following way:

```
var address = sequelize.define("address", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY,
        allowNull: false
    },
    /* ... */
});
```

And now I'm trying to retrieve all addresses in distance 25Km radius:

```
const distance = models.sequelize.fn('ST_Distance', models.sequelize.col('coordinates'), city.coordinates);

return models.address.findAll({
    where: models.sequelize.where(distance, { $lte: 25000 })
});
```

That translates into the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "addresses" AS "address" WHERE 
ST_Distance("coordinates", "type" = \'Point\' AND "coordinates" IN (41.544031, -8.426646))
<= \'25000\';
```

That throws the error: column "type" does not exist.

sequelize: 3.23.3,
postgres: 9.4.12

What am I doing wrong?